# fetch data of parent view when using paartail view to form submit MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created Comment box in Parent View as a partail view to add comment. below is my Comment model.

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CMT_ID { get; set; }

    private DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime cmd_ad
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; }
    }
    public string cmd_content { get; set; }
    public string t_email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SPID { get; set; }
    public virtual service_provider service_provider { get; set; }
```

from partail View I have to submit cmd_content,t_email and SPID.Below is partail view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Food")){
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<table>
 <tr><td></td> <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.cmd_content)</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Email</td><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.t_email)</td></tr>
 <tr><td></td> <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.t_email)</td</tr></table><p><input type="submit" value="Comment" class="btn btn-success" /></p>}
```

I have created action methods for submit data from partail View. Action method Details method for parent View.AddComment is Action method for _Comment partail View.Below is my Controller method.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        ImageData details = new ImageData();

        var sp_details = (from s in db.service_provider
                          join p in db.pictures on s.SPID equals p.SPID
                          join c in db.cities on s.City_ID equals c.City_ID
                          where s.SPID == id
                          select new ImageData()
                          {
                              Sp_name = s.Sp_name,
                              SPID = s.SPID,
                              pic = p.pic
                          });

        return View(sp_details);
    }

    public ActionResult AddComment()
    {
        return PartialView("_Comment");
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddComment(comment cmt)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.comments.Add(cmt);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Food");
        }
        return PartialView("_Comment", cmt);
    }
```

When Someone add comment partail view should submit cmt_content,t_emil,SPID. My problem is How do I fetch SPID from parent View. It is same as parameter pass to Details Action method. Can Somebody help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the way you have this set up, there won't be anything other than the partial on post, anyways. Posting to an action that returns a partial view, should only be done via AJAX. If you're not using AJAX to post, then you should always return `View`, or you'll lose all your layout.

That said, you need to step back and understand the platform you're developing on: the Web. The web operates on the HTTP protocol and the TCP/IP protocols, on a lower level. Importantly, all of these are designed to be stateless. The whole idea was to create a mesh network where nodes could come online and drop off without bringing down the rest of the network. To achieve that, no individual server can have intimate knowledge of communication with a particular client, or if that server were to go down, then the client can no longer resume.

At a higher level, this translates into each request being a unique thing, uninformed by any request that proceeded it. When you post, the only thing that exists server-side is *what you posted*. That variable that existed before is long gone. If you need some value again in the post action, then you need to post it along with every thing else, or rerun whatever logic got you the value in the first place after the post. It's not just going to be there waiting for you.

Comment: I'm new to MVC 4.If you can give Simple example or tutorial link,It would be Great help for me.

Comment: my problem is fetch id value of parent view.

Comment: Again, there is no such thing as "id value of parent view" in this context. It doesn't exist. If you need that value, you need to set it in something like a hidden input, and then post that along with everything else.

Comment: can you suggest a way to do that?

Comment: I just did: add a hidden input to your form.

Comment: how do I fetch SPID passed to details View?

Comment: No offense, but this is pretty basic MVC 101 stuff. Perhaps you just need to spend some time with the tutorials at http://asp.net/mvc. You add a hidden input and bind it to a param on your action or a property on your model. Then, in your post action, you utilize that param/property.